# Checking data in the label with AJAX ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm checking if there is a data and continutiy in the label with ASP.NET's Ajax addon and I want to pop-up open if my condition is satisfied and pop-up close if it's not in the code behind. But there is a bug. When the data in the label is the same with the new recevied data is same pop-up opens continously. So I'm trying to avoid that.

```
  public void func () 

            {                 
                        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cons"].ConnectionString;
                        using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(con))                            
                        {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                        cnn.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = cnn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users Where name=@namee";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@namee", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label4.Text;
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
                            while (dr.Read())
                        {                            
                        read  = dr["id"].ToString();
                        read1 = dr["name"].ToString();
                        read2 = Convert.ToDateTime( dr["date"]);
                     online = Convert.ToInt32(dr["online"]);                            
                        }
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;                               
                        TimeSpan ts = now - read2;
                        int diffday = ts.Days;
                       nameee = read1;                            
                        if (nameee != "" && diffday <=0 && online==1)             

                        {                            
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "error", "error();", true);
                        Session["usersname"] = nameee;
                        string url = "Users.aspx";
                        string newWindow = "window.open('" + url + "','_blank','height=1000,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=yes,resizable=yes,titlebar=no');";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OpenWindow", newWindow, true);
                         cnn.Dispose();
                        cnn.Close();                           
                        }
                        }

        }








  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
                                <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="3000"  /> 
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2"  runat="server" >

<Triggers> 
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" eventname="Tick"/> 
                 </Triggers>  

                                <ContentTemplate>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Your posted code is full of bugs.

Comment: no this code is correct but i have bug with popup